# UITableViewCell setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted is always false

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm overriding `UITableViewCell` class to add a ripple/ink effect to my cells. Based on iOS Material Component [List](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/develop/components/List), the only thing I should do is to override the setHighlighted method like this:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    if (highlighted) {
        [self startInk];
    } else {
        [self endInk];
    }
}
```

This technique works with `UICollectionViewCell` but I'm not sure if it should work with `UITableViewCell`.

[image: 1]

Whenever I push the cell and I don't raise my finger, this method never gets called. Only gets called when and raise it and `highlighted` is always `false`.

Anyone knows how to override this long press to start an animation?

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: Because setHighlighted is what it is: past tense "highlighted" means it is called only AFTER highlight for cell is finished. You probably need to use touchesDown or others

Comment: That's make sense. I finally achieve it overriding (void)touchesBegan:withEvent: method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get it by overriding (void)touchesBegan:withEvent: method. This is my code based on iOS Material Component [List](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/develop/components/List):

```
@property(strong, nonatomic, nonnull) MDCInkView *inkView;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    self.lastTouch = location;
    if (self.selectionStyle != UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone){
        NSInteger selectionStyle = self.selectionStyle;
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             [self startInk];
                         }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                                                   delay:0.0
                                                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                                              animations:^{
                                                  [self endInk];
                                              }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                  self.selectionStyle = selectionStyle;
                                              }];
                         }];
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)startInk {
    [self.inkView startTouchBeganAtPoint:_lastTouch animated:YES withCompletion:nil];
}

- (void)endInk {
    [self.inkView startTouchEndAtPoint:_lastTouch animated:YES withCompletion:nil];
}
```